# How to pass variable from a function to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Variable 'url' is undefined inside click function but it is available inside buildUrl function

html:

```
<label class="secondary" for="car01">
    <input type="checkbox" id="car01" name="carid" value="car01" checked>Select<span></span>
</label>
<label class="secondary" for="car02">
    <input type="checkbox" id="car02" name="carid" value="car02" checked>Select<span></span>
</label>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //Init
  buildUrl();
 var url; 
    // Listen to change event
    $('.selected-cars input[type=checkbox]').change(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
             $(this).val();
                buildUrl();
                $('.button').click(function () {
                  console.log('Click happen');
                  console.log('url', url);
                    $('.button').attr('href', url);
                });
        }else{
             $(this).val();
                buildUrl();
        }
    });
    // Build URL
    function buildUrl(){
          var carIds = $( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).serialize();
          var url = "abc.com?" + carsIds;
          console.log('url', url);
    };
});
```

Comment: But you are never setting the url. Like `url = conquestUrl;` or something

Comment: `var url` in `buildUrl` shadows the outer `var url`, which is why you can't see the value (`abc.com...`) inside the `click` handler.

Comment: If I deleted var url; problem still there :(

Comment: nono, don´t delete it there! leave the top one, and remove the `var` from the function `buildUrl`, so it uses the one defined before, instead of creating a new one that will be destroyed when the function is done executing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `var` in `var url = "abc.com?" + carsIds;`.

The `var` keyword creates a new `url` which is locally scoped to the `buildUrl` function. If you leave off `var` you will be assigning to the `url` that you declared in the outer scope.

```
function buildUrl(){
      var carIds = $( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).serialize();
      url = "abc.com?" + carsIds;
      console.log('url', url);
};
```

However, a function which modifies a variable outside its own scope like that often makes for code that is harder to follow, especially when its not part of a known design pattern.

It seems like you also want to update the `href` of the button right away, instead of waiting for someone to click on it. I would recommend simplifying your code to:

```
$(document).ready( function ( ) {

    // Listen to change event
    $( '.selected-cars input[type=checkbox]' ).change( function ( ) {

        var carIds = $( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).serialize();
        var url = "abc.com?" + carsIds;

        // Update button href
        $( '.button' ).attr( 'href', url );

    });

});
```

If you want to have a `buildUrl` function so that you can call it elsewhere, then make it return the url instead of assigning to a variable from an outer scope:

```
$(document).ready( function ( ) {

    // Listen to change event
    $( '.selected-cars input[type=checkbox]' ).change( function ( ) {

        var url = buildUrl();

        // Update button href
        $( '.button' ).attr( 'href', url );

    });

    function buildUrl ( ) {
        var carIds = $( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).serialize();
        return "abc.com?" + carIds;
    }

});
```

Comment: @ShoaibUd-Din You were also not updating the `href` of the button until it is clicked. I posted a simplified version that updates the `href` each time a checkbox toggles.